# How can Interceptor in python be applied

Tags: python, interceptor

I need to know when a function is called and do something after calling the function. It seems Interceptor can do it.

How can I use Interceptor in python ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done using decorators:

```
from functools import wraps


def iterceptor(func):
    print('this is executed at function definition time (def my_func)')

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print('this is executed before function call')
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print('this is executed after function call')
        return result

    return wrapper


@iterceptor
def my_func(n):
    print('this is my_func')
    print('n =', n)


my_func(4)
```

Output:

```
this is executed at function definition time (def my_func)
this is executed before function call
this is my_func
n = 4
this is executed after function call
```

`@iterceptor` replaces my_func with the result of execution of the `iterceptor` function, that is with `wrapper` function. `wrapper` wraps the given function in some code, usually preserving the arguments and execution result of wrappee, but adds some additional behavior.

`@wraps(func)` is there to copy the signature/docstring data of the function `func` onto the newly created `wrapper` function.

More info:

- http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/PythonDecorators.html
- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/

Comment: The function my_func locates in a class in a library, not in any class of my code. So based on what you said I should change the library, and I want not to do it as far as possible.

Comment: You can change the way you are applying the decorator, fancy `@` syntax does exactly this, only on local functions: `my_lib.my_func = interceptor(my_lib.my_func)`

Comment: Thank you @Andrew for your help. It solved the problem.